# EC2 instance IP address monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a AWS Direct Connect setup for our private EC2 instances. A few main concerns are:

- Someone changing the IP addressing on our EC2 instance to public addressing
- Someone setting up a Transit Gateway and connecting it to our EC2 instances

I’ve done some research and it looks as though AWS Config and CloudTrail would be the best resources to monitor this. If so, what kind of checks/events/parameters/etc. should be monitored so we can begin setting up alerts and notifications for the activity?

For example, I read with AWS config there is an `ec2-instance-no-public-ip` rule.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Create ec2 in private subnet with NAT:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html

Comment: Agreed. This would keep the instance private. Mind you, an Admin could modify the Route Table and convert a private subnet into a public subnet -- you would need to restrict such permissions to staff you can trust. In general, only assign "least privilege" to people. This means give them enough permission to do their job, but not "all permissions".

Comment: This doesn’t really answer what’s trying to be accomplished tbh. I’m not really looking for the “how” to keep an instance private, i’m looking for ways to monitor and alert for when it happens that the EC2 instances that are private get configured in a way that makes them publicly available. If you could provide insight on that it would be greatly appreciated. Yes, least privilege is great but when a user (or a threat actor has compromised said user) with the granted privilege breaks from what is expected or user makes an error im looking for notifications/alerts on the 2 scenarios mentioned.